Can $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$ not be the maximal order of a number field, but contain maximal orders of subfields?
Assume we have three number fields $K_1, K_2$ and $L$ with $K_1 \cap K_2 = \mathbb{Q}$ and $L = K_1 K_2$ (the composite field). Let further $\alpha \in \mathcal{O}_L$ (the maximal order of $L$) such that $\mathcal{O}_{K_1}[\alpha] \subseteq \mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathcal{O}_{K_2} \subseteq \mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$. Does it follow that $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha] = \mathcal{O}_L$?
At first, I was sure that this must be false, since in my experimence, non-maximal order are very badly behaved. I did some computational experiments on quadratic fields, but never was able to construct a counterexample. Then, I was able to prove (using a length, elementary calculation) that the statement is true if we restrict to
$$ d_1 \equiv d_2 \equiv 3 \mod 4, \quad K_1 = \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{d_1}], \quad K_2 = \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{d_2}]$$
and any $\alpha$ of the form $\frac 1 k (\sqrt{d_1} + \sqrt{d_2})$ with any integer $k \in \mathbb{Z} \setminus \{0\}$.
Of course, this is quite a serious restriction, nevertheless, it got me wondering. I assume if the statement was true, then the easiest way to prove it might be using localization. Unfortunately, I somehow fail to make use of the "single-generatedness" of $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$, both locally and globally.
Note that the statement is false if $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$ is replaced by any order $\mathcal{O}$ even in the quadratic setting, for example for
$$ K_1 = \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{3}], \quad K_2 = \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{7}], \quad \mathcal{O} = \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{3}, \sqrt{7}] \subseteq \mathcal{O}_L, \quad L = K_1 + K_2 $$
we find
$$ \mathcal{O}_{K_1} = \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{3}], \mathcal{O}_{K_2} = \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{7}] \subseteq \mathcal{O} $$
but $\mathcal{O} \subsetneq \mathcal{O}_L$, since the latter contains also $\frac 1 2 (\sqrt{3} + \sqrt{7})$.
Edit I am now very sure again that the statement is false. I might expand this edit more as soon as I have a better understanding of my intuition that says so.

Correct the typos in the 1st paragraph: $\mathcal O_{K_1}[\alpha] \subset \mathbb Z$ and $K_1 + K_2$ are not correct, e.g., you meant $K_1K_2$ as the composite field. In the 2nd paragraph your use of $k$ in the denominator of $\alpha$ makes no sense since $k$ is never defined.

What do you mean by "give" $K_1K_2$? This field is not the set of all sums $x_1 + x_2$.

Oh sorry, I don't know how I got the idea that it would be...
